# How to stop duplicate data in jquery mobile after navigationg between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am creating a chat application in jQuery Mobile.The problem is that when you navigate between pages and come back to the chat page when submitting data the data is resent according to the number of times one has navigated between other pages

When i perform a full page refresh data is sent only once as required.

I have tried adding `data-ajax = false` to the `href` of the link(button) but still it doesnt work?

The html code:

```
<form id="form_message_user" method="post"    
action="#user_requestmoreinfo_page
  ">
  <div data-inset="true">
 <label for="requestmessage" class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
     <textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="requestmessage" 
 id="text_user_message" placeholder="Type message to send "></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitmessage" />

 </form>
```

The form is on a page with

```
<div data-role="page" id="user_requestmoreinfo_page" data-theme="e">
```

The submission code:

```
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#user_requestmoreinfo_page',function(e){
        var id_from = localStorage.loggedin_id;
        var id_to = localStorage.user_schoolls_id;
var message = $("#text_user_message").val();

$('#form_message_user').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 if(message > 0 ){
            // Send data to server through the Ajax call
            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                $.ajax({url: '127.0.0.1/php/send.php',
                    data: {message:message,id_from:id_from,id_to:id_to},
                    type: 'post',                   
                    async: 'true',
                         dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });                   
        } else {
            alert('Please enter the message');
        }           
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });

  });
```

On success the console.log() displays the json data according to the number of page navigations before getting to the page(#user_requestmoreinfo_page);

Example:

If i had to navigate between other pages 3 times the console.log() will show output of 3 times

Comment: `reload` does only work when the 'url' argument is a URL (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load). Please post the HTML form code and the jQuery submit code.

Comment: Is there a  way to ensure a reload when dealing with ids as references(#..)

Comment: Wrap code in `pagecreate` when you add event listeners, not `pageshow`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My guess is that you're binding the event handler to the #form_message_user element each time the #user_requestmoreinfo_page event is handled. I'd try adding

```
$('#form_message_user').off('submit');
```

directly before

```
$('#form_message_user').on('submit', function(e){
    // function body continues
```

You could also try using .one:

```
$('#form_message_user').one('submit', function(e){
    // function body continues
```

According to the docs, that should have the same affect as .off() followed by .on():

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This will not work in case of the jqm page duplication bug, as there will be two forms with the same ID in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your solution it now works ive added, .off(submit), and the .one(submit).

Comment: The other solution i found was to add pageinit instead of pageshow

Comment: Curious as to why my answer was downvoted, when the OP accepted it as the answer.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI, if my answer was acceptable, do I get the bounty? Thanks!

Comment: Yap you get it my internet had some problems i couldnt get into stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons why you experience this behaviour.

1) Code multiplication. Bind the code to `pagecreate`, not `pageshow`, as the latter event is triggered every time the page is displayed, duplicating the submit code and causing multiple events.

2) Page duplication. This is a well-known bug in jQM that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168027/jquerymobile-selectwidget-not-showing-after-second-page-visit/). In short, the first page (and its form) is duplicated in DOM under certain circumstances. To fix it, describe the path to the HTML document with the attribute `data-url`, and place it within the `page div`. Example code:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="mysite/path/index.html" id="user_requestmoreinfo_page">
```

Here is a rework of your code with added buttons for page navigation:

**Example code:**

```js
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#user_requestmoreinfo_page', function(e) {

  $('#form_message_user').on('submit', function(e) {
    //Cancel default action (https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
    e.preventDefault();

    //var id_from = localStorage.loggedin_id;
    //var id_to = localStorage.user_schoolls_id;
    var message = $("#text_user_message").val();

    //Validate
    if(message == "")
      alert('Please enter the message');

    // Send data to server through the Ajax call
    // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
    alert("Thank you for your comment.");
    $.ajax({
      url: '127.0.0.1/php/send.php',
      data: {
        message: message,
        id_from: id_from,
        id_to: id_to
      },
      type: 'post',
      async: 'true', //<- true is default
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
      },
      complete: function() {
        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div data-role="page" data-url="<mysite>/index.html" id="user_requestmoreinfo_page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <form id="form_message_user" data-ajax="false">
        <label for="requestmessage">Message:</label>
        <textarea data-inline="true" id="text_user_message" placeholder="Type message to send"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true" />
      </form>
      <a href="#second" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Next page</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>
        Second page
      </p>
      <a href="#user_requestmoreinfo_page" data-role="button" data-inline="true">First</a>
      <a href="#third" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Third</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="third">
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>
        Third page
      </p>
      <a href="#user_requestmoreinfo_page" data-role="button" data-inline="true">First</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```